# Qt, Set an exclusive clipping region

Tags: qt, qpainter

In Qt you can set a clipping region for a QPainter with modes ReplaceClip or IntesectClip but I miss an "ExcludeClip". How would you draw (filling) a "donut" (a circle with a transparent hole) without reverting to intermediate QPixmaps?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found a solution operating with regions:

```
QRegion rg1(outerRect,QRegion::Ellipse);
QRegion rg2(innerRect,QRegion::Ellipse);
QRegion rg3=rg1.subtracted(rg2);

painter->setClipRegion(rg3);
```